# Transforming categorical data to vectors

Tags: classification, categorical-data, word2vec

I am faced with a classification problem. One of my features consists of categorical data with 150 factors (these are related to jobs i.e. *sales assistant*, *desk clerk* etc).

My initial approach was to use the `randomForest` package (in R) but it appears that it cannot handle more than 52 levels.

I have heard about word embedding and `word2vec`. My question is, would it makes sense to convert my categorical data to vectors, rather than one-hot encoding? Could it affect model accuracy?

Answer (score 2):

It could make sense to train an embedding for your categorical data, if you can associate each category with likely contexts (analogously to training a skip-gram or continuous bag-of-words for word vectors). In the example that you give, perhaps you can differentiate salespeople from managerial positions using some chosen characteristics. My main concern with this approach is that you could easily overfit, since word vector embeddings are usually trained with millions of examples.